# how can i add weight to networkx edges?

Tags: python, networkx, adjacency-matrix

i have basic dataframe which looks like this

```
     A  B  C  D ... Z
foo1 1  0  1  0 ... 0
foo2 0  0  0  1 ... 0
foo3 0  1  0  0 ... 1
foo4 1  0  1  1 ... 0
```

(actual shape = 330, 1113)
and i transformed this to adjacency matrix

```
   A  B  C  D ... Z
A
B
C
D
..
Z
```

(actual shape = 1113, 1113)

this matrix have only binary values, 
and i could get graph's several centralities(degree, closeness, betweenness) using networkx

and then, i gave some values to dataframe like

```
     A  B  C  D ... Z
foo1 3  0  3  0 ... 0
foo2 0  0  0  2 ... 0
foo3 0  5  0  0 ... 5
foo4 4  0  4  4 ... 0
```

(actual shape = 330, 1113 and values in a row are all same)

also i transformed this to adjacency matrix and calculate centralities
but i have the same result with the binary values.

is this situation normal?
i thought those centralities would be different because of the weight, but it isn't.

i want the column(e.g. A) with high value would be more central, but the both result are same.

why this happening? how can i solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`nx.from_numpy_array`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html), the values are from the fed adjacency array are set as edge weights, so that should do as you want. Using some example array:

```
df.values
array([[6, 0, 4, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 4, 8]])

G = nx.from_numpy_array(df.values)

G.edges(data=True)
#EdgeDataView([(0, 0, {'weight': 1}), (0, 2, {'weight': 1})...
```

---

As per the various centrality algorithms available in [Centrality](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/centrality.html), for weights to be considered you have to modify the attribute names, so that they are taken into account. For instance, for the [`closeness_centrality`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.closeness_centrality), from the docs:

> If the ‘distance’ keyword is set to an edge attribute key then the shortest-path length will be computed using Dijkstra’s algorithm with that edge attribute as the edge weight.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I compute betweenness for a weighted graph, where G has been created using the directions from @yatu and networkx has been imported as nx:

```
BC = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=False, weight='weight')
```

And here's a function to compute and compare BC values using a simple bar graph. The argument "labels" is a dictionary of labels, where values are strings, e.g. something of the form

```
labels={0:'A',1:'B',2:'C',3:'D'}

def network_betweenness_bar(G, labels):
    # Compute Betweenness Centrality Values and plot as bar graph
    BC = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=False, weight='weight')
    BC = list(BC.values())
    BC = [round(elem, 2) for elem in BC]
    x = np.arange(len(labels))
    axis_labels = list(labels.values());
    plt.bar(x, BC)
    plt.xticks(x, axis_labels)
    plt.title('Betweenness Centrality', fontsize=18)
    return BC
```